# Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, filereader, nosuchelementexception

When I execute my program which is a simple file reader I get the exception:
->add event
Exception in thread "main" Name of event: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I have tried reading earlier posts about the same exception but without any help, tried hasNextLine(); Didnt work. Not sure where problem lies.

```
    while (tangentbord.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        line.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("->" + line);
        if (line.equals("add event")) {
            GL.addEvent();
        }
```

Below is the method which decides the events name and is where the exception is thrown.

```
private String setEventName() {
    String EventName;
    do {
        System.out.print("Name of event: ");
        EventName = tangentbord.nextLine();
        EventName.trim();
        if (EventName.length() <= 1 || EventName.isEmpty() || EventName.contains("  ")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
        }
    } while (EventName.length() <= 1 || EventName.isEmpty() || EventName.contains("  "));
    EventName= normalisera(EventName);
    for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
        if (events.get(i).EventName().equals(EventName)) {
            System.out.println("Event allready exist");
            EventName = null;
        }
    }
    return EventName;
}
```

Comment: The exception message should tell you exactly which line caused it.

Comment: Why are you checking `tangentbord` and then reading from `scanner` ? Ideally you'd be checking `scanner` before you read from `scanner` and be checking `tangentbord` before reading from that.

Comment: And once you fix the scanner mismatch, you will want to use hasNextLine()...

Comment: Use proper naming conventions, variable names start with a lower case.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry about that, tangentbord is scanner, mistyped.

Comment: @JohnHascall as it states in the text above, I have allready tried it

Comment: @JohnHascall The exception happens at EventName = tangentbord.nextLine();

Comment: @A.Bohlund is it the same object ? If so then you're reading two lines at a time, one in the main while loop and one in `setEventName()`, the line read in the while will not correspond to the same line as the line read in `setEventName()` and when you read the last line in the while loop the file will have reached its end when you enter `setEventName()` not sure if this makes sense or I misunderstood what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

The "mismatch" in the top code block:

```
while (tangentbord.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        ...
}
```

is a red herring!

In the second code block, in `setEventName()`, you need to check `tangentbord.hasNextLine()` before you do:

```
EventName = tangentbord.nextLine();
```

(or wrap it in a `try ... catch` if you prefer).